# What brand is this outdoor spigot?

Tags: outdoorfaucet

Can anyone identify the make of this outdoor faucet? The stem is 6" long and 9/16" in diameter.

[image: Here is outdoor picture]

Comment: Is there an actual problem you're trying to solve, or are you just curious? It's usually not all that important to know the brand of faucet...

Comment: I need to replace the stem. As you can see, the groves holding the handle have worn smooth and I have a make-shift solution. At some point, I will need to replace the packing nut gasket and to do that I'll have to remove the handle. I may not be able to get the screw out. I took the stem to the local Ace Hardware and no cigar. They didn't have a match.

Comment: In what way did it not match? You an probably buy a complete rebuild kit where the packing seals, shaft, at handle all work together nicely.

Comment: Given the machine screw I inserted to keep it from spinning on the shaft, I may no longer be able to remove the handle. Therefore, I cannot replace the gasket/washer that seals the main packing nut. I would like to just replace the entire stem with a new handle that is secured by the splines on the stem (the splines are totally gone on mine). To do this, I need to know the make of this faucet.